# Add unique rows to dataframe (opposite of intersect)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, unique, na

I am relatively new to R but slowly finding my way. I encountered a problem, however, and hope someone can help me.

Let's say I two dataframes (lets call them A and B), both containing survey responses. A contains all responses from the first set of people. B contains the responses of the second set of people, plus the people of the first set but with their responses set to NA. An example:

```
Dataframe A:
Household Individual Answer_A Answer_b
1         2          5        6
1         3          6        6
2         1          2        3

Dataframe B:
Household Individual Answer_A Answer_b
1         1          3        6
1         2          NA       NA
1         3          NA       NA
2         1          NA       NA
2         2          4        7
```

I want to get one dataframe with all individuals and their responses:

```
Dataframe C:
Household Individual Answer_A Answer_b
1         1          3        6
1         2          5        6
1         3          6        6
2         1          2        3
2         2          4        7
```

If I only have two datasets I can use `rbind.fill`, with `rbind.fill(B, A)` to get dataframe C, as then the NAs in B are overwritten with answers in A.
But... if I would have to add a third dataset, D, that would consist of NAs for people in A and B, I would not be able to use this solution. What would I be able to do then? I've looked at intersect, outersect, different forms of join, but can't seem to think of a good solution.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try `merge`? Something like `na.omit(merge(dfA, dfB, all = TRUE))`

Comment: you can just remove the rows with NAs in dfB, and rbind with dfA, rbind(dfA,dfB[complete.cases(dfB),])

Comment: @sotos I tried on my dataset, but ended up with an empty dataframe. Merging them 'the normal way' (without `na.omit`) drops almost all observations (from 21000 to 83), but can't see why exactly those 83 are kept.

Comment: No idea why....

Comment: @StupidWolf eventually this proved to be the easiest solution. Thank you!

Comment: glad it worked for you @Niicole16 !

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can `left_join` and then use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(B, A, by = c("Household", "Individual")) %>%
  mutate(Answer_A = coalesce(Answer_A.x, Answer_A.y),
         Answer_B = coalesce(Answer_b.x, Answer_b.y)) %>%
  select(-matches("\\.x|\\.y"))

#  Household Individual Answer_A Answer_B
#1         1          1        3        6
#2         1          2        5        6
#3         1          3        6        6
#4         2          1        2        3
#5         2          2        4        7
```

**data**

```
A <- structure(list(Household = c(1L, 1L, 2L), Individual = c(2L, 
3L, 1L), Answer_A = c(5L, 6L, 2L), Answer_b = c(6L, 6L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))

B <-  structure(list(Household = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Individual = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), Answer_A = c(3L, NA, NA, NA, 4L), Answer_b = c(6L, 
NA, NA, NA, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into this. Didn't think of using mutate & coalesce.